# Using legacy 'setup.py install' for python-multipart, since package 'wheel' is not installed

Tags: python, aws-lambda, anaconda, virtualenv

I have installed wheel using the below command --

`pip3 install wheel --target lambda-layer-dependencies/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages`

Then when I'm trying to install packages using the below command I get --

`Using legacy 'setup.py install' for python-multipart, since package 'wheel' is not installed.`

`pip3 install -r src/requirements.txt --upgrade --target lambda-layer-dependencies/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages`

Am I missing something here?

I'm using venv and my base python is anaconda (wheel is already installed in conda env as well.).

Comment: If you have a Conda env, then Conda Forge also provides `python-multipart`: `conda install -c conda-forge python-multipart`